# Calling Dispatcher.Invoke() on Dispatcher thread

Tags: c#, wpf, com, dispatcher

I'm having a problem displaying a WPF window using Window.Show:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>   Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Fair enough - the standard way to fix this is to use Dispatcher.Invoke to ensure that the window is displayed on the Dispatcher thread.

The strange thing is that as far as I can tell, the code is already running on the Dispatcher thread.

This code triggers the exception:

```
if (Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread || 
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Current thread is not Dispatcher");
}

window.Show(); // throws InvalidOperationException
```

This code works fine:

```
if (Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread || 
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Current thread is not Dispatcher");
}

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(window.Show);
```

As I understood it, if the current thread is the dispatcher thread, then calling Dispatcher.Invoke should be equivalent to directly calling the method. Clearly this is wrong, but can someone explain why?

To complicate the issue, this code is in a method that is called via COM from a VB6 application (yeah, I know). What effects could that be having?

Comment: Try comparing Thread.CurrentThread to App.Current.Dispatcher.Thread. It's hard to tell whether or not you are running on the dispatcher thread without seeing the full method you are calling window.Show() from.

Comment: You can't get a helpful answer on a question like this.  The unhelpful approach is [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/12/12/6749902.aspx).

Comment: I've tried Application.Current.Dispatcher and Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher - they're the same. I've updated the post to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @roomaroo, there's something wrong about your 1st code snippet `Dispatcher.Current.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread`, as there is no `Dispatcher.Current` property in WPF.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks - VS froze as I was writing the question so I couldn't copy and paste!

Comment: What thread did you create the window on? I am guessing not the UI thread?

Comment: @roomaroo, interesting, so the only difference is that you call `window.Show` directly in the 1st case, while you're supposedly on the main UI thread in both cases?

Comment: @Noseratio Exactly - and I don't understand why that should make a difference

Comment: @kenjara The window is created in the current method on the current thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is a wrong .NET synchronization context (or lack of thereof) in the 1st case.

As far as I understand, this code is called from an unmanaged host, which naturally doesn't have a .NET synchronization context installed on the main UI thread.

Try this in the 1st case:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new { System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current });
window.Show(); // throws InvalidOperationException
```

I expect you to see `{ Current = null }` in the debug output.

For the 2nd case, do this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new { System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current });
    window.Show();
});
```

This should output `{ Current = System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext }`.

Comment: Good call. The first case gives { Current = System.Windows.Threading.SynchronizationContext } rather than null, but it's not a DispatcherSynchronizationContext.

Comment: The code at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/R/4990431309c71f1a.html shows that the Dispatcher changes the SynchronizationContext before calling the Action.

Comment: I'm experiencing something like the original question and looking for ways to debug it. Unfortunatly I don't see current= null in either case. What is the proper way to see which thread owns my object?

Comment: @Adam, *What is the proper way to see which thread owns my object?* - what object are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I meant the object which gets 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' error. (My debugging efforts really suggested that the current running thread and object.Dispatcher.Thread was the same. However I was looking at the wrong object, so now I figure that the answer to my question is object.Dispatcher.Thread!)